# Multiple Ajax login forms

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have mulitple logins on my WordPress, when the user logs in I want to redirect them to another page. E.g. login form 1, takes you to page 1. Login form 2, takes you to page 2.

I have followed the tutorial http://natko.com/wordpress-ajax-login-without-a-plugin-the-right-way/ which was excellent in gaining an understanding of how this works.

All is working well, however form 2 is not submitting and seems to be getting stuck on 'Sending user info, please wait..'

Could anyone please help?

```
<div class="half-login">
  <div class="global-login">
    <div class="login-dets">
      <div class="loginform">
        <form id="login" action="login" method="post">
          <p class="status"></p>
          <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
          <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
          <input class="submit_button" type="submit" value="Login" name="submit">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="exhibition-login">
    <div class="login-dets">
      <div class="loginform">
          <form id="login2" action="login" method="post">
            <p class="status2"></p>
            <input id="username2" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
            <input id="password2" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            <input class="submit_button" type="submit" value="Login" name="submit">
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'security' ); ?>
          </form>
        <?php } ?>          
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // Perform AJAX login on form submit
    $('form#login').on('submit', function(e){
        $('form#login p.status').show().text(ajax_login_object.loadingmessage);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: ajax_login_object.ajaxurl,
            data: { 
                'action': 'ajaxlogin', //calls wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin
                'username': $('form#login #username').val(), 
                'password': $('form#login #password').val(), 
                'security': $('form#login #security').val() },
            success: function(data){
                $('form#login p.status').text(data.message);
                if (data.loggedin == true){
                    document.location.href = "link-1/";
                }
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Perform AJAX login on form submit
    $('form#login2').on('submit', function(e){
        $('form#login2 p.status2').show().text(ajax_login_object.loadingmessage);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: ajax_login_object.ajaxurl,
            data: { 
                'action': 'ajaxlogin', //calls wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin
                'username': $('form#login2 #username2').val(), 
                'password': $('form#login2 #password2').val(), 
                'security': $('form#login2 #security2').val() },
            success: function(data){
                $('form#login p.status2').text(data.message);
                if (data.loggedin == true){
                    document.location.href = "/link-2/";
                }
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    }); 

});
```

PHP

```
function ajax_login_init(){

    wp_register_script('ajax-login-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/ajax-login-script.js', array('jquery') ); 
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-login-script');

    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-login-script', 'ajax_login_object', array( 
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'redirecturl' => home_url('/home-page-new'),
        'loadingmessage' => __('Sending user info, please wait...')
    ));

    // Enable the user with no privileges to run ajax_login() in AJAX
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin', 'ajax_login' );
}

// Execute the action only if the user isn't logged in
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    add_action('init', 'ajax_login_init');
}

function ajax_login(){

    // First check the nonce, if it fails the function will break
    check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'security' );

    // Nonce is checked, get the POST data and sign user on
    $info = array();
    $info['user_login'] = $_POST['username'];
    $info['user_password'] = $_POST['password'];
    $info['remember'] = true;

    $user_signon = wp_signon( $info, false );
    if ( is_wp_error($user_signon) ){
        echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__('Wrong username or password.')));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>true, 'message'=>__('Login successful, redirecting...')));
    }

    die();
}
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Check the console for errors.

Comment: ERROR:- POST http://www.project-progress.co.uk/dropbox/global/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php - 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: ALERT:- [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #security: <input type=​"hidden" id=​"security" name=​"security" value=​"4c5967f9d8">​ <input type=​"hidden" id=​"security" name=​"security" value=​"4c5967f9d8">​

Comment: Ah, the `security` field I assume is some form of authentication which is failing due to the duplicate `id` attributes and the PHP is then returning you an unauthorised response. You need to fix the duplicate ids (by making them unique) and then include the values correctly in the AJAX requests

Comment: Once this is fixed, is there any easy way to redirect the forms seperately? Both are redirecting to home-page-new. Thanks!

Comment: I can't really answer that without knowing the structure of your site. I'd suggest your next job would be to DRY this up, as you should be able to handle both forms in a single JS `submit` event handler.

Comment: Hi Rory, you were correct! It was just confusion in the JS file that was breaking this. Instead of targeting the parent direct, using $(this) and finding the element fixed the issue! Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem, glad to help - I added the above as an answer for you

Comment: Kindly follow https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/, for using nonce with ajax in wordpress. You need to pass nonce parameter in ajax call according to above guide and verify nonce in php function. You might face 403 forbidden error because of this wrong configuration of nonce.

Answer (score 0):

Given the error you mention in the comments:

> ALERT:- [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #security: ​

It appears that the `security` field is some form of authentication which is failing in the request due to the duplicate `id` attributes. The PHP is then returning an unauthorised response due to the missing/invalid data in the request.

To fix this you need to fix the duplicate ids (by making them unique) and then include the values correctly in the AJAX requests.